# Moving AD Objects from array based on their current OU with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So my task is to move computer accounts in AD from their current Production-OU to the correspondent Pilot-OU. I received a text file that has all the computer account names in it but nothing else

```
computer1
computer2
computer3
...
```

Unfortunately I am pretty new in the company so I don't really know the OUs from experience and there is no database. I am also new to PowerShell and my PowerShell expert colleague is on vacation.
So I am trying to put together a script something like this

```
$computers = Get-Content ".\computers.txt"
$computers | ForEach-Object {
IF object1's OU = Production1 {
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Pilot1"
ELSE {
IF object1's OU = Production2 {
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Pilot2"
ELSE {
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Pilot3"
}
}
}
}
}
```

I tried to figure out what cmdlet I could use to get the current OU and tried piping to `Get-Member` but I am unable to figure out which filters or parameters to use and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the current OU

```
((Get-ADComputer "Computername").DistinguishedName).Split(",")[1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That gave me enough info to complete my script :)